# Easiest way to replicate this decision flow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm looking to replicate the decision flow found here: https://codepen.io/jason-monaghan/pen/bGbQVwM

I'd like there to be two buttons, When one is clicked, a section expands with two more buttons. some sections will have text instead of buttons.

I've attached a user flow I created.

[User flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQc4I.jpg)

I tried to use toggle buttons but found an issue when both buttons were clicked:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.button').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings(".item").toggle();
  });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.button-1').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings(".item-1").toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.item,
.item-1 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <button class="button">Yes</button>
  <button class="button-1">No</button>
  <div class="item-1">
    Not eligible
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-2">
      <p>Eligible</p>
      <button class="button-3">Click</button> <button class="button-4">Click</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are not toggling the previously selected item. You should do something like:

```
$(this).siblings(".item-1").hide();
$(this).siblings(".item").show();
```

when you click a single button. Or disable the other button so that it cannot be clicked.

Comment: I've tried this but for some reason, once it get's into the buttons inside the content boxes it doesn't work
(https://codepen.io/jason-monaghan/pen/wvwQmPj)

Comment: In that example the .item-2 is hidden from the css. Do you know how to use browser's developer tools?